# DocuSign REST API via Proxy Server

Tags: java, rest, proxy, docusignapi

I have the following code that I used from a [Docusign Rest API walk through](http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/requestSignatureFromDocument). Since I am behind a proxy I have added the proxy information.

```
public HttpURLConnection initializeRequest(String url, String method, 
   String body, String httpAuthHeader) {
        try {

            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, 
                new InetSocketAddress("proxyServer address", proxyPort));

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection(proxy);
            conn.setRequestMethod(method);
            conn.setRequestProperty("X-DocuSign-Authentication",
                httpAuthHeader);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            if (method.equalsIgnoreCase("POST")) {
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
                    "multipart/form-data; boundary=BOUNDARY");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
            } else {
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            }
            return conn;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e); // simple exception handling
                                           // please review it
        }
    }
```

**This was running fine** but lately the proxy requires authentication and I am getting a unauthorized 401 error on my rest calls.

I did change the code to have the authenticator in it but am still having the same problem, any suggestions what I can try other than this?

```
public HttpURLConnection initializeRequest(String url, String method, String body, String httpAuthHeader) {
        try {

            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, 
                new InetSocketAddress("proxyServerAdress", intPort));

            Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {

                public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return (new PasswordAuthentication("username",
                        "password".toCharArray()));
                }
            };
            Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);


            conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection(proxy);

            conn.setRequestMethod(method);
            conn.setRequestProperty("X-DocuSign-Authentication",
                httpAuthHeader);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            if (method.equalsIgnoreCase("POST")) {
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
                    "multipart/form-data; boundary=BOUNDARY");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
            } else {
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            }
            return conn;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e); // simple exception handling
                                           // please review it
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use [requestb.in](http://requestb.in/) to see what you're sending to DocuSign. Your basic authentication with proxy is probably being sent to DocuSign which isn't expected. Complain to your proxy people. The fact that they broke your working app should be their problem to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Use [requestb.in](http://requestb.in/) to see what you're sending to DocuSign via the proxy server.

Your basic authentication with the proxy is probably being sent to DocuSign which isn't expected by the platform.

Complain to your proxy people. The fact that they broke your working app should be their problem to fix...